(De) Serializing list of objects containing polymorphic generics in C# .NET 8 with System.Text.Json
When trying to serialize a list where objects are derived types of generic and generic base, I end up with the error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Specified type 'CSharpLanguageTestingApp.CustomResult1[T]' is not a supported derived type for the polymorphic type 'CSharpLanguageTestingApp.CustomResult1[CSharpLanguageTestingApp.AggregateTwo]'. Derived types must be assignable to the base type, must not be generic and cannot be abstract classes or interfaces unless 'JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling.FallBackToNearestAncestor' is specified.'

FallBackToNearestAncestor does nothing for me at this time.
Example class:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpLanguageTestingApp
{
    public class AggregateOne
    {
        int iAmAggregateOne { get; set; } = 1;
    }

    public class AggregateTwo
    {
        public int iAmAggregateTwo { get; set; } = 2;
    }

    [JsonPolymorphic]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(CustomResult<>), "CustomResult")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(dbCustomResult<>), "dbCustomResult")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(sbCustomResult<>), "sbCustomResult")]
    [JsonDerivedType(typeof(apiCustomResult<>), "apiCustomResult")]
    public class  CustomResult<T>
    {
        public int iAmAResult { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class  dbCustomResult<T> : CustomResult<T>
    {
        public int iAmADbResult { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class sbCustomResult<T> : CustomResult<T>
    {
        public int iAmASbResult { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class apiCustomResult<T> : CustomResult<T>
    {
        public int iAmAnApiResult { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class CompositeResult
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = "CompositeResult";

        [JsonConverter(typeof(PolymorphicListConverter))]
        public List<object> IndividualResults { get; set; } = new();
    }
}

Converter:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharpLanguageTestingApp
{
    public class PolymorphicListConverter : JsonConverter<List<object>>
    {
        public override List<object> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            var results = new List<object>();

            // Ensure we're at the start of the array
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            {
                while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                {
                    if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
                    {
                        using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
                        {
                            JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;

                            if (root.TryGetProperty("$type", out JsonElement typeElement))
                            {
                                string typeName = typeElement.GetString();
                                Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);

                                if (type != null)
                                {
                                    var json = root.GetProperty("Data").GetRawText();
                                    var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, type, options);
                                    results.Add(obj);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return results;
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<object> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();

            foreach (var result in value)
            {
                if (result != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Get the runtime type of the object
                        var resultType = result.GetType();

                        writer.WriteStartObject();
                        writer.WriteString("$type", resultType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
                        writer.WritePropertyName("Data");

                        // Serialize the object as is
                        string json = "";

                        try
                        {
                            json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, options); // try 1
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error serializing object of type {result.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, result, resultType, options); // try 2
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error serializing object of type {result.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
                        }

                        writer.WriteEndObject();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error serializing object of type {result.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
                        throw; // Rethrow or handle the exception as needed
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
}

Program to test:
CompositeResult compositeResult = new CompositeResult();

compositeResult.IndividualResults.Add(new dbCustomResult<AggregateOne>());
compositeResult.IndividualResults.Add(new CustomResult<AggregateTwo>());
compositeResult.IndividualResults.Add(new sbCustomResult<AggregateTwo>());
compositeResult.IndividualResults.Add(new apiCustomResult<AggregateOne>());

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new PolymorphicListConverter());

string json = "";

try
{
    json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(compositeResult, options);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}

Console.WriteLine(json);

Tried to add converters but I have way to many aggregates to make it easy to manage the json options converters. Tried modifying the converter but so far no luck
So far, I cannot get generic derived types and base types to play nicely along in the same list when serializing / deserializing
Removing the CustomResult from the list works:
{
    "Name": "CompositeResult",
    "IndividualResults": [
          {
              "$type": "CSharpLanguageTestingApp.dbCustomResult\u00601[[CSharpLanguageTestingApp.AggregateOne, CSharpLanguageTestingApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], CSharpLanguageTestingApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
              "Data": { "iAmADbResult": 0, "iAmAResult": 0 }
          },
          {
              "$type": "CSharpLanguageTestingApp.sbCustomResult\u00601[[CSharpLanguageTestingApp.AggregateTwo, CSharpLanguageTestingApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], CSharpLanguageTestingApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
              "Data": { "iAmASbResult": 0, "iAmAResult": 0 } 
          },
          {
              "$type": "CSharpLanguageTestingApp.apiCustomResult\u00601[[CSharpLanguageTestingApp.AggregateOne, CSharpLanguageTestingApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], CSharpLanguageTestingApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
              "Data": { "iAmAnApiResult": 0, "iAmAResult": 0 }
        }
    ] 
}


The reason you are getting an exception is that the JsonDerivedType attributes you have applied to you base class CustomResult<T> specify open generic types like dbCustomResult<>.  However, the derived types specified in the attribute are supposed to be the actual, concrete types of the objects being serialized -- and an instantiated POCO never has an open generic as its type.  Perhaps you were hoping that System.Text.Json automatically would close the open generic types by substituting in the generic parameter T, however no such functionality has been implemented by MSFT.
So, what are you options?
Firstly, you could use the polymorphism support built into System.Text.Json as intended, specifying all possible closed generic types that might be encountered in your list.  The easiest way to do this would be to extract a non-generic abstract base type for CustomResult<T>, apply all derived type attributes to it, then use it in your list as follows:
[JsonPolymorphic]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(CustomResult<AggregateOne>), "CustomResult<AggregateOne>")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(dbCustomResult<AggregateOne>), "dbCustomResult<AggregateOne>")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(sbCustomResult<AggregateOne>), "sbCustomResult<AggregateOne>")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(apiCustomResult<AggregateOne>), "apiCustomResult<AggregateOne>")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(CustomResult<AggregateTwo>), "CustomResult<AggregateTwo>")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(dbCustomResult<AggregateTwo>), "dbCustomResult<AggregateTwo>")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(sbCustomResult<AggregateTwo>), "sbCustomResult<AggregateTwo>")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(apiCustomResult<AggregateTwo>), "apiCustomResult<AggregateTwo>")]
public abstract class CustomResultBase;

public class  CustomResult<T> : CustomResultBase
{
    public int iAmAResult { get; set; } = 0;
}

public class CompositeResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "CompositeResult";

    public List<CustomResultBase> IndividualResults { get; set; } = new();
}

The long list of derived type attributes is kind of ugly, but with this approach you can completely forgo writing a converter.  You also get type safety for your IndividualResults list, making this the preferred solution in my opinion.
Demo fiddle #1 here.
Alternatively, you could avoid System.Text.Json's polymorphism support entirely and write your own converter like one of the ones from Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?.  However, your current converter attempts to instantiate any type specified in the JSON file.  This introduces a severe, well-known security vulnerability into your code, the Friday the 13th JSON Attacks vulnerability.  This is a reported problem with Newtonsoft which System.Text.Json avoids by only allowing whitelisted types to be deserialized.  If you deserialize any type specified by Type.GetType(typeName); you will introduce the same vulnerability into your code, allowing attackers to craft JSON payloads that could delete all files on your disk or run arbitrary code.  For more see:

External json vulnerable because of Json.Net TypeNameHandling auto?
TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json.
OWASP Cheat Sheet Series Deserialization Cheat Sheet

If you do chose to go this route you will need to ensure that, at the minimum, known attack gadget types are not deserialized.  I rewrote your code to add in the necessary checks, and in addition I separated the list converter and the polymorphic item converter into separate classes, avoided preloading the JSON into a JsonDocument, and fixed a couple bugs in which known properties were not skipped correctly.  The new converters look like:
public class PolymorphicListItemConverter<TBase> : ListItemConverterDecorator<TBase, PolymorphicConverter<TBase>>;

public class PolymorphicConverter<TBase> : JsonConverter<TBase>
{
    const string TypeProperty = "$type";
    const string DataProperty = "Data";

    protected virtual Type? BindToType(string? typeName)
    {
        // TODO: You will need to think how to sanitize your types further
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeName))
            return null;
        if (JsonExtensions.ContainsKnownDangerousTypeNames(typeName))
            throw new JsonException($"Invalid type {typeName}");
        return Type.GetType(typeName);
    }

    public override TBase? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var comparison = options.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive ? StringComparison.Ordinal : StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null)
            return typeof(TBase).IsValueType && Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(TBase)) == null ? throw new JsonException() : default;
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            throw new JsonException();
        if (!reader.TryScanForwardForPropertyValue(TypeProperty, comparison, out var readerCopy))
            throw new JsonException("Missing type name");
        var type = BindToType(readerCopy.GetString());
        if (type == null || !type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(TBase)))
            throw new JsonException($"Invalid type name {readerCopy.GetString()}");
        TBase? value = default;
        while (reader.ReadAndAssert().TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
        {
            var match = DataProperty.Equals(reader.AssertTokenType(JsonTokenType.PropertyName).GetString(), comparison);
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
            if (match)
                value = (TBase?)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, type, options);
            else
                reader.Skip();
        }
        return value;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TBase value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value is null)
        {
            writer.WriteNullValue();
            return;
        }
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        var valueType = value.GetType();
        writer.WriteString(TypeProperty, valueType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
        writer.WritePropertyName(DataProperty);
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, valueType, options);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

public class ListItemConverterDecorator<TItem, TConverter> : JsonConverter<List<TItem>> where TConverter : JsonConverter, new()
{
    readonly JsonConverter<TItem> itemConverter = (JsonConverter<TItem>)(new JsonSerializerOptions { Converters = { new TConverter() } })
        .GetConverter(typeof(TItem));

    public override List<TItem>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.Null)
            return null;
        else if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            throw new JsonException();
        var list = new List<TItem>();
        while (reader.ReadAndAssert().TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            list.Add(itemConverter.Read(ref reader, typeof(TItem), options)!);
        return list;
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<TItem> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (value is null)
            writer.WriteNullValue();
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in value)
                itemConverter.Write(writer, item, options);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    // Taken from 
    // https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Deserialization_Cheat_Sheet.html#known-net-rce-gadgets
    // As of November 2024
    static readonly string [] KnownDangerousTypes = 
        [
            "System.CodeDom.Compiler.TempFileCollection",
            "System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller",
            "System.Activities.Presentation.WorkflowDesigner",
            "System.Windows.ResourceDictionary",
            "System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider",
            "System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource",
            "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.SystemManager.WinForms.ExchangeSettingsProvider",
            "System.Data.DataViewManager",
            "System.Xml.XmlDocument",
            "System.Xml.XmlDataDocument",
            "System.Management.Automation.PSObject",
        ];
    
    public static bool ContainsKnownDangerousTypeNames(string typeName) =>
        KnownDangerousTypes.Any(n => typeName.Contains(n));

    public static bool TryScanForwardForPropertyValue(ref readonly this Utf8JsonReader reader, string name, StringComparison comparison, out Utf8JsonReader copy)
    {
        copy = reader.AssertTokenType(JsonTokenType.StartObject);
        while (copy.ReadAndAssert().TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndObject)
        {
            var match = name.Equals(copy.AssertTokenType(JsonTokenType.PropertyName).GetString(), comparison);
            copy.ReadAndAssert();
            if (match)
                return true;
            else
                copy.Skip();
        }
        return false;
    }
                                    
    public static ref Utf8JsonReader ReadAndAssert(ref this Utf8JsonReader reader) { if (!reader.Read()) { throw new JsonException(); } return ref reader; }
    public static ref readonly Utf8JsonReader AssertTokenType(ref readonly this Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType type) { if (reader.TokenType != type) throw new JsonException(); return ref reader; }
}

And your model would be modified as follows, with all JsonDerivedType and JsonPolymorphic attributes removed:
public class  CustomResult<T>
{
    public int iAmAResult { get; set; } = 0;
}

public class CompositeResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "CompositeResult";

    [JsonConverter(typeof(PolymorphicListItemConverter<object>))]
    public List<object> IndividualResults { get; set; } = new();
}

And your CompositeResult can now be round-tripped successfully.  Demo fiddle #2 here.
You need to think about how to ensure that protected virtual Type? BindToType(string? typeName) only returns types that you expect.  One possibility would be to, once again, introduce a non-generic base class for CustomResult<T> also also constrain the generic parameter T to be of some expected polymorphic type.  Having done so, you will be much less likely to allow dodgy types to be deserialized.

Hi,
Wow, thanks for the detailed information and the work that went into this.
I ended up creating a base class that is generic base and that solved my issue without having to declare a whole bunch of JsonDerivedType. Kinda feels stupid to do it that way, but it works. I put all of my JsonDerivedTypes on that base class and voila.
Wanted to mark your answer as the answer, but cant seem to do that as I am new on stackoverflow.
Kind regards,

@OliR - you're welcome.  If you want to accept an answer, you can do so by clicking the green check mark on the upper left of the answer.
